# Unable to locate error "list index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running a program provided by a third party with Python 3.7.4. The error seemed straightforward:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/opt/pixet/libs/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2314, in main
    script_name=sys.argv[0] or 'easy_install',
list index out of range
```

But after several attempt I was unable to locate the error.

I start the program by running a short script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from setuptools.command.easy_install import main
    main()
```

Line 2314 in `setuptools.command.easy_install.py` is within the definition of `main()`:

```
...
2296
2297 def main(argv=None, **kw):
2298     from setuptools import setup
2299     from setuptools.dist import Distribution
2300
2301     class DistributionWithoutHelpCommands(Distribution):
2302         common_usage = ""
2303
2304         def _show_help(self, *args, **kw):
2305             with _patch_usage():
2306                 Distribution._show_help(self, *args, **kw)
2307
2308     if argv is None:
2309         argv = sys.argv[1:]
2310
2311     with _patch_usage():
2312         setup(
2313             script_args=['-q', 'easy_install', '-v'] + argv,
2314             script_name=sys.argv[0] or 'easy_install',
2315             distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands,
2316             **kw
2317         )
2318
...
```

Whatever I've done couldn't remove this error, actually I even inserted blank lines before `def main(...)` so that it looks like:

```
...
2312
2313
2314
2315
2316
2317 def main(argv=None, **kw):
2318     from setuptools import setup
2319     from setuptools.dist import Distribution
2320
2321     print("trace")
...
```

It still reports error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/opt/pixet/libs/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2314, in main
list index out of range
```

The content of line 2314 changed in the error, so I was modifying the right file. But as I added `print()` to `main()`, nothing was printed. I don't understand how this error occurs at this line with nothing on it.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Rather than `print("trace")` why not `print(sys.argv)` and see what that says :-)

Comment: Nothing printed with `print(sys.argv)`. Actually I replaced `main()` with only `print(sys.argv)` in it. It didn't print and still reported error at line 2314. Is **line 2314** special to python?

Comment: maybe problem is in some missing char (ie. closing `)`) in some line before. You could add more `print()` before some lines before - to see which print will be displayed.

Comment: OK. I added print() to most of the function entries and saw no print. Accidentally the python environment (company provided) crashed, and after I reopened it, I got those tracing information. Seems that the environment caches the file so that those print didn't work (but not entirely as I could see the content of the line changed). So frustrated.